# My application do not open and goes hang when i use app.config to read client machine database connection string

Tags: database

i made a application and used app.config file to read connection string acc to client machine (this is my first application for client machine) but application hangs and shows error on client machine. On my system i use my connection string

My System Connection String:

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DELL5520\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Lakshay;Integrated Security=True");
```

Connection string i used acc. to app.config file :

```
namespace Lakshay

{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string ctr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Lakshay.Properties.Settings.Lakshay1onnectionString"].ConnectionString;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}

}
```

App.Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Lakshay.Properties.Settings.LakshayConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB\Lakshay.dbo;Initial Catalog=Lakshay;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

you obviously have a typo:

name of connectionString in your app.config:

```
"Lakshay.Properties.Settings.LakshayConnectionString"
```

but you're trying to access the connection string `Lakshay1ConnectionString` in your code.