# I'm getting error when using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; namespace with controls new point syntax in C#

Tags: c#, excel, location, controls

i'm trying to change location of controls using

```
label1.Location = new Point(x,y);
```

but i also want to export data from data grid view to excel, for doing this i'm using

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

but when i use this, namespace compiler shows error in

```
label1.Location = new Point(x,y);

Error : 'Point' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Drawing.Point' and 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Point'
```

Code for exporting data to excel :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

    Workbook wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);

    Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)Excel.ActiveSheet;

    Excel.Visible = true;

    ws.Cells[1, 1] = "ID";

    ws.Cells[1, 2] = "Products Name";

    ws.Cells[1, 3] = "Products Id";

    ws.Cells[1, 4] = "Products Price";

    ws.Cells[1, 5] = "Selling Price";

    for (int j = 2; j <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            ws.Cells[j, i] = dataGridView1.Rows[j - 2].Cells[i - 1].Value;
        }
    }
```

Code for new points :

```
linkLabel7.Show();

linkLabel7.Location = new Point(293, 59);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aliases for your namespaces

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Drawing = System.Drawing;
```

and use it like this

```
label1.Location = new Drawing.Point(x,y);
```

look at the MSDN reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)

Comment: Thanku. It worked. But now i'm exporting data in excel, only table coulms name appeared in excel not data.
do you need the full code of exporting ? (i used internet to make this code,not my own)

Comment: and please also check this question. i'm giving you link for that question. [click this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191359/my-application-do-not-open-and-goes-hang-when-i-use-app-config-to-read-client-ma)

Comment: that's a different question. if my answer worked for you, please mark my answer as accepted. for a different problem use a different question.

Comment: Please check this too ... i'm giving you link for that question. [click this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191359/my-application-do-not-open-and-goes-hang-when-i-use-app-config-to-read-client-ma)